# Products filtered by attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, product

i want to display on my product view all the products that have the same value of an attribute.
In my case, i want to show all the products(books) who have the same editor as my current product.
When i iterate, it renders all the products.

> ```
>  <?php  $same_editions=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')-  >addAttributeToFilter('editeur',array('eq'=>$_product->getEditeur()))->load();
> ?>
> <p>
> <?php foreach($same_editions as $editeur){
>   $editeur = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($editeur->getId());?>
> <?php echo $editeur->getName();?>    
> </p>
> <?php }?>
> ```

My attribute name is : editeur.

Comment: then what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it "echo"s all the list of products name even those who don't even have the attribute. It's like it doesn't filter.

Comment: Check editeur attribute setting at Manage Attribute  on backed which a setting Use in product listing =Yes and also check give proper value or not $_product->getEditeur()

Comment: That was it. Use in product listing was set to "No".Thank you so much.